# Jquery Simple FAQ

Tags: jquery

has anyone ever used the JQuery plugin SimpleFAQ? I am trying to get it working and have successfully done so in Safari and Chrome. But the exact same code will not work in Firefox or Opera. My efforts lie here >>>>>>> http://www.northlight-studios.co.uk/dev/snaplocks/help-faq.html

I would appreciate it if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Seems to be working fine in FF to me....What version of FF are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

author of jQuery.simpleFAQ here. I've talked with "mtwallet" over email about this. He had included some of my sample code from http://jkdesign.org/faq/ (the main project site) which had some "console" statements in it. These of course only work on browsers where a console object is defined, such as IE 8, Safari, Chrome, and Firefox with Firebug installed.

After removing that code he was able to get this working.

Comment: Got it working perfectly, many thanks for all your help Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://oraguide.com - similar concept but everything is streamlined / hosted in the cloud.